Estimation of autocorrelation from unevenly sampled time series
Consider $n$ distinct time series $X^{(1)}, \ldots, X^{(n)}$, indexed by time (time ranging from 0 to 1), such that:

each time series $X^{(i)}$ has a different number of observations,
the time indices are not regularly spaced,
the time indices can differ for each time series,
each time series only has a few observations (less than 10).

As an example,
$X^{(1)}$ can be a series with 5 values at times taken at times $t = 0.1;\, 0.4; \, 0.5;\, 0.55;\, 0.6$,
while $X^{(2)}$ can be a series with only 3 values at times $t = 0.07;\, 0.35; 0.5$
and $X^{(3)}$ can be a series with 7 values at times $t = 0.02;\, 0.38;\, 0.39;\, 0.5;\, 0.6;\, 0.7;\, 0.98$.
I am assuming that the time series are independent, identically distributed and share the same autocorrelation function (assume stationarity of the series).
What would be a good way to estimate this auto-correlation function (additional assumptions can be made if needed)?

Similar questions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169150/variance-and-autocorrelation-with-missing-and-or-unevenly-spaced-data-in-time-se
